# Can another thread release a lock held by another thread in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to understand threading in Python via [this website](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/). Here, it has the following code for a single producer/consumer-type problem:

```
import random 

SENTINEL = object()

def producer(pipeline):
    """Pretend we're getting a message from the network."""
    for index in range(10):
        message = random.randint(1, 101)
        logging.info("Producer got message: %s", message)
        pipeline.set_message(message, "Producer")

    # Send a sentinel message to tell consumer we're done
    pipeline.set_message(SENTINEL, "Producer")

def consumer(pipeline):
    """Pretend we're saving a number in the database."""
    message = 0
    while message is not SENTINEL:
        message = pipeline.get_message("Consumer")
        if message is not SENTINEL:
            logging.info("Consumer storing message: %s", message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    format = "%(asctime)s: %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO,
                        datefmt="%H:%M:%S")
    # logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    pipeline = Pipeline()
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        executor.submit(producer, pipeline)
        executor.submit(consumer, pipeline)

class Pipeline:
    """
    Class to allow a single element pipeline between producer and consumer.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.message = 0
        self.producer_lock = threading.Lock()
        self.consumer_lock = threading.Lock()
        self.consumer_lock.acquire()

    def get_message(self, name):
        logging.debug("%s:about to acquire getlock", name)
        self.consumer_lock.acquire()
        logging.debug("%s:have getlock", name)
        message = self.message
        logging.debug("%s:about to release setlock", name)
        self.producer_lock.release()
        logging.debug("%s:setlock released", name)
        return message

    def set_message(self, message, name):
        logging.debug("%s:about to acquire setlock", name)
        self.producer_lock.acquire()
        logging.debug("%s:have setlock", name)
        self.message = message
        logging.debug("%s:about to release getlock", name)
        self.consumer_lock.release()
        logging.debug("%s:getlock released", name)
```

IIUC, the consumer lock is acquired and released in different threads (and the producer too). Is this possible? It feels like I'm missing something because then couldn't any thread release a lock held by another thread?

Comment: Victor thanks for asking this. I have been breaking my head about because of this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock):

> The class implementing primitive lock objects.
> Once a thread has acquired a lock, subsequent attempts to acquire it
> block, until it is released; **any thread may release it**.

In fact this technique is frequently used to orchestrate the threads. If you look closely two `Lock` objects are created in the `Pipeline` class. The `consumer_lock` is acquired in initialization which means if two threads start concurrently, the consumer thread would hit its `Lock` object in `self.consumer_lock.acquire()` and gonna be blocked. It's gonna wait for producer thread to put something in there. There has to be something to be consumed after all.

When producer puts something in, it releases the `consumer_lock` so that it can go ahead consumes it.

Comment: Thanks, did not realize the documentation had this. Am I correct in saying that in C++, only the thread that acquired the lock may release it?

Comment: @VictorM Unfortunately I didn't do threading in C++ in the past.

Comment: @VictorM The [C++ standard library says "Undefined Behavior"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/unlock) if one thread attempts to unlock a `std::mutex` instance that was locked by a different thread. In my experience, that's how it is with most threading libraries: Either it's undefined, or it's outright forbidden. In most languages and libraries, if there's a thing that can be "locked" by one thread and "unlocked" by another, then that thing is called "semaphore" (often, "binary semaphore" or "counting semaphore.")